# Python: set background of a box in a boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am using matploitlib boxplot to create a figure like the following:

[image]

Using this code:

```
# Create a figure instance
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 4))

# Create an axes instance
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim([0, 1.2])

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot,widths=(0.5, 0.5))
plt.setp(bp['boxes'], linewidth=1)

# Save the figure
plt.xticks([1, 2], ['A', 'B'],fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
#fig.savefig('fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

What I am trying to get at is to set background for each box so they have different colors.

Thanks

Comment: see an example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the following argument to boxplot:

```
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot,widths=(0.5, 0.5),patch_artist=True)
```

and assign each box a unique color using:

```
bp['boxes'][0].set( facecolor = '#1b9e77' )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only partly doing what you want, but maybe it helps you out to find the answer to your problem. You can use

```
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot,widths=(0.5, 0.5),notch=True, patch_artist=True)
```

to fill the plot. In order to change the color take a look at this [Example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html).

Comment: Yes, adding the patch_artist helped me to resolve my problem.